# Create T with two different constructors

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
public void Add<T>() where T : ISetup, new() {
  new T().Run();
} // Add
```

This can be used as follows:

```
Add<SettingsSetup>()
```

Where SettingsSetup is:

```
public class SettingsSetup : ISetup {  
  private Func<String, String> _resolver;
  public SettingsSetup(Func<String, String> resolver) {
    _resolver = resolver;
  }
  public void Run() { }
}
```

I would like to be able to use Add as follows:

```
Add<SettingsSetup>()
```

Or passing a parameter to be used on SettingsSetup:

```
Add<SettingsSetup>(Func<String, String>)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What makes you think it isn't?  Did you try simply writing another method overload?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't able to do new T(Func<String, String> resolver) in Add method

Comment: Remember that ISetup is an interface ... I could make it a base class. Basically SettingsSetup or any other setup should allow to be used using Func<String, String> or nothing ...

Comment: What does the `ISetup` interface look like?  Does it just have the `Run()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Resolver` property to `ISetup`, and set it from an overload of `Add`:

```
public void Add<T>(Func<String, String> resolver) where T : ISetup, new() 
{
  var setup = new T();
  setup.Resolver = resolver;
  setup.Run();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my comment below the question.

Comment: look in my comment and the link, which is below Edit. There's an answer, but Dave done it too..

Answer (score 1):

simple:

```
public interface ISetup
{
    void Run();
    int SomeProp { get; set; }
}

public class Setup : ISetup
{
    public void Run()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int SomeProp
    {
        get
        {
            return 2;
        }
        set
        {
            SomeProp = value;
        }
    }
}

 public bool MyMethod<T>(T t) where T :  ISetup
 { 
      return t.SomeProp != 2;
 }
```

and use:

```
var setup = new Setup();
bool response = MyMethod<Setup>(setup); // false
```

**Edit**:
here's good source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx